# Simple plotly plots in R

Tags: r, jupyter, plotly

I can't seem to figure out why I can't successfully plot the simplest of dataframes in `R` using `plotly`. Here's an example where I want to plot a 2D scatter plot of a dataframe named `b`:

```
b <- data.frame(cat=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), rabbit=c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5), dog=c(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5))
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(b, x = cat, y = rabbit, mode= "markers")
```

If you print `b`, you'll see that it's a dataframe of 5 samples, with column names `cat`, `rabbit` and `dog`, as expected. However when I execute the above in Jupyter (don't know if it matters), I get the following error:

> Error in plot_ly(b, x = cat, y = rabbit, mode = "markers"): object 'rabbit' not found
>
> Traceback:
>
> 1. plot_ly(b, x = cat, y = rabbit, mode = "markers")

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, `b` is a legitimate dataframe, and `cat` and `rabbit` are its column names.

Comment: I'm using RStudio and your code executes without error messages, there. Thus, it may be a `jupyter` problem. Don't forget to add a `print(p)` to see the chart.

Comment: For `Jupyter` to show plots you add `embed_notebook(b)` but the error occurs before the plot is embedded in the notebook. I agree that it's probably a `Jupyter` problem, but have no idea what it could be--there are no error messages about dependencies or anything else more informative than `object not found`.